# How to get the name/description of an exception?

Tags: windows, winapi, exception

How do you get the name and/or description of an [SEH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657(VS.85).aspx) exception **without** having to hard-code the strings into your application?

I tried to use `FormatMessage()`, but it truncates the message sometimes, even if you specify to ignore inserts:

```
__asm { // raise access violation
    xor    eax, eax
    mov    eax, [eax]
}
```

Raises an exception with the code `0xC0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)`.

```
char msg[256];
FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), 0xC0000005,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    msg, sizeof(msg), NULL);
```

Fills `msg` with the truncated string: "`The instruction at 0x`".

Comment: Wow this really does seem broken. It works for various messages, but I can't get it to work for STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION for the life of me.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on this now but have you tried FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM?

Comment: morechilli: Yes, I tried it already, but it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7915329/7194773

Answer (score 4):

Structured exception codes are defined through NTSTATUS numbers. Although someone from MS suggests [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/259693) (the article has been moved to [here](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/259693)) using [FormatMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert NTSTATUS numbers to strings, I would not do this. Flag `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` is used to convert result of [GetLastError()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) into a string, so it makes no sense here. Using flag `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` along with `ntdll.dll` will lead to incorrect results for some codes. E.g., for `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` you will get `The instruction at 0x`, which is not very informative :) .

When you look at the strings that are stored in `ntdll.dll` it becomes obvious that many of them are supposed to be used with the [printf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) function, not with the [FormatMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx). For example, the string for `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` is:

`The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.`

`%0` is treated by [FormatMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx) as the escape sequence meaning message terminator, not an insert. Inserts are %1 to %99. That's why flag `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` does not make any difference.

You might want to load the string from `ntdll.dll` and pass it to [vprintf()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) but you will need to prepare arguments exactly as the string specifies (e.g. for `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` it's `unsigned long`, `unsigned long`, `char*`). And this approach has major drawback: any change in the number, order or size of arguments in `ntdll.dll` may break your code.

So it's safer and easier to hard code the strings into your own code. I find it dangerous to use strings prepared by someone else without coordination with me :) and moreover for other function. This is just one more possibility for malfunction.

Comment: This is so broken, but its too late to change.

Comment: @davidbak What is broken?

Comment: That they had every opportunity initially (when NT was created) to make these proper event log strings (%1 style formatting) and instead made them printf format strings.  And then they've never provided a substitute.  There must be hundreds of programs - if not thousands - that have special code to format AVs for logging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Does this apply?

http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2001-May/000801.html