# Windows/C++: FormatMessage() with GetExceptionCode() ignores FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS

Tags: c++, windows, exception, formatmessage

I would like to using code similar to the following to report divide-by-zero, access violations, etc.  My problem is that, despite setting the flag `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS`, messages are truncated at the position of the insert.

```
__try
{
    int *p=0;
    int i = *p; // access violation
}
__except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
    char  message[1024];
    FormatMessageA(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        GetModuleHandleA("NTDLL.DLL"),
        GetExceptionCode(),
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL),
        message, 
        sizeof (message), 
        0);
    OutputDebugStringA(message);
}
```

The above code yields `"The instruction at 0x"` in the debug output which is not terribly helpful.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [You are not alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321898/how-to-get-the-name-description-of-an-exception).