# Listing message IDs and symbolic names stored in a resource-only library (DLL) using Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, dll

We would like to list the contents (key/value pairs) of messages embedded in a resource-only library (DLL)

The resource library is defined as specified [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
mc -s EventLogMsgs.mc
rc EventLogMsgs.rc
link /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /NOENTRY /MACHINE:x86 EventLogMsgs.Res
```

A sample EventLogMsgs.mc may be:

```
; // - Event categories -
; // Categories must be numbered consecutively starting at 1.
; // ********************************************************

MessageId=0x1
Severity=Success
SymbolicName=INSTALL_CATEGORY
Language=English
Installation
.

MessageId=0x2
Severity=Success
SymbolicName=QUERY_CATEGORY
Language=English
Database Query
.

...
```

We tried to use EnumResourceTypes() Win32 API as following:

```
...
HMODULE hMod=NULL;
hMod = LoadLibraryA( "C:\\temp\\EventLogMsgs.dll" ); 
if (hMod != NULL) 
{
    EnumResourceTypes( hMod, (ENUMRESTYPEPROC)TypesCallback, 0) ;
    FreeLibrary(hMod);
}
...

BOOL WINAPI TypesCallback( HMODULE hModule, LPTSTR lpType, LONG lParam )
{
    char buffer[100];
    if ((ULONG)lpType & 0xFFFF0000) 
        sprintf( buffer, "%s\n", lpType); 
    else 
        sprintf(buffer, "%u\n", (USHORT)lpType); 

    cout << "Type: " << buffer << std::endl;

    EnumResourceNames( hModule, lpType, (ENUMRESNAMEPROC)NamesCallback, 0 );
    return true;
}

BOOL WINAPI NamesCallback( HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR lpType, LPTSTR lpName, LONG lParam )
{
    char buffer[100];
    if ((ULONG)lpName & 0xFFFF0000) 
        sprintf(buffer,"%s\n", lpName); 
    else 
        sprintf(buffer, "%u\n",(USHORT)lpName); 
    cout << "Name: " << buffer << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

The result is a high level listing of the resource types and their "names/identifiers", e.g.,

```
...
Type: 11
Name: 1

Type: 16
Name: 1

Type: 24
Name: 2
...
```

11 (RT_MESSAGETABLE) is the message table resource type ([See all resource types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Ideally we would want to list *ALL* the actual messages' symbolic names and identifiers in the resource library.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've enumerated the resources in the module which tells you the name of each resource of a specific type. Once you've done that you need to load the resource to examine its content. In your case you need the resource of type `RT_MESSAGETABLE` that is named `1`.

You now need to use `FindResource`, `LoadResource` and `LockResource` to get a pointer to the beginning of the message table structures. You can then use the `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA` struct , and in turn `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK` and `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_ENTRY` to unpack the content of the message table. This [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14444/Enumerating-Message-Table-Contents) goes into more detail on the process.

Here's a rather naff C program that enumerates your message table:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ProcessBlock(MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA* data, MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK* block)
{
    MESSAGE_RESOURCE_ENTRY* entry = (MESSAGE_RESOURCE_ENTRY*) ((unsigned char*)data + block->OffsetToEntries);
    for (DWORD id = block->LowId; id <= block->HighId; id++)
    {
        if (entry->Flags == 0x0001) // wide char
            printf("%d, %ls", id, entry->Text);
        else if (entry->Flags == 0x0000) // ANSI
            printf("%d, %s", id, entry->Text);
        entry = (MESSAGE_RESOURCE_ENTRY*) ((unsigned char*)entry + entry->Length);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("C:\\desktop\\EventLogMsgs.dll"); 
    if (hMod == NULL) return 1;

    HRSRC hRsrc = FindResource(hMod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), RT_MESSAGETABLE);
    if (hRsrc == NULL) return 1;

    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hMod, hRsrc);
    if (hGlobal == NULL) return 1;

    MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA* data = (MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA*)LockResource(hGlobal);
    if (data == NULL) return 1;

    for (DWORD block = 0; block < data->NumberOfBlocks; block++)
        if (!ProcessBlock(data, &data->Blocks[block]))
            return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1, Installation
2, Database Query
3, Data Refresh
1000, My application message text, in English, for message id 1000, called from %1.
1002, My generic information message in English, for message id 1002.
1004, The update cycle is complete for %%5002.
5001, Sample Event Log
5002, SVC_UPDATE.EXE
-2147482647, My application message text, in English, for message id 1001, called from %1.
-2147482645, My generic warning message in English, for message id 1003, called from %1.
-2147482643, The refresh operation did not complete because the connection to server %1 could not be established.
```

Please excuse my appalling C. Neither C nor C++ are languages that I am remotely fluent in. However, the code will at least show you how to extract the information you desire.

Comment: Thank you very much, David - we will follow the instructions you provided to test.

Comment: @alexg For my own edification, I wrote some code to enumerate the message table. I hope it helps.

Comment: Successfully confirmed - both with your very clear & concise code and the Code Project solution :) Thanks a lot for your help!!!