# Marshaling a message table resource

Tags: c#, resources, pinvoke

I need to read a Message Table resource in C#.

I'm basically trying to port to C# the code in the answer to this question: [Listing message IDs and symbolic names stored in a resource-only library (DLL) using Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122552/listing-message-ids-and-symbolic-names-stored-in-a-resource-only-library-dll-u)

My problem is that I cannot correctly marshal the `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA` and `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK` structures, which are defined like this (in `<winnt.h>`):

```
typedef struct _MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK {
    DWORD LowId;
    DWORD HighId;
    DWORD OffsetToEntries;
} MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK, *PMESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK;

typedef struct _MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA {
    DWORD NumberOfBlocks;
    MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK Blocks[ 1 ];
} MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA, *PMESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA;
```

In `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA`, `NumberOfBlocks` is the number of `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK` entries in the `Blocks` array (even if it is declared as an array with a single element).

Since I do not know at compile time the array size, I tried to marshal the struct declaring `Blocks` as a pointer, and then using `Marshal.PtrToStructure` like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK {
    public IntPtr LowId;
    public IntPtr HighId;
    public IntPtr OffsetToEntries;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA {
    public IntPtr NumberOfBlocks;
    public IntPtr Blocks;
}

class Program {

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string fileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindResource(IntPtr hModule, int lpID, int lpType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LockResource(IntPtr hResData);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const int RT_MESSAGETABLE = 11;
        IntPtr hModule = LoadLibrary(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\msobjs.dll");
        IntPtr msgTableInfo = FindResource(hModule, 1, RT_MESSAGETABLE);
        IntPtr msgTable = LoadResource(hModule, msgTableInfo);
        var data = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA>(LockResource(msgTable));
        int blockSize = Marshal.SizeOf<MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.NumberOfBlocks.ToInt32(); i++) {
            IntPtr blockPtr = IntPtr.Add(data.Blocks, blockSize * i);
            // the following line causes an access violation
            var block = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK>(blockPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work, however, and I'm getting an access violation error.

How can I marshal a structure like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not close, these structures do not contain IntPtr.  DWORD is a 32-bit integer.  The variable-length structures used in resource formats are very awkward in C#, there is no decent way to declare them.  Best thing to do is to use Marshal.ReadXxx() to read the fields.

The only struct declaration that's still useful is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK {
    public int LowId;
    public int HighId;
    public int OffsetToEntries;
}
```

And then you slug it out like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    const int RT_MESSAGETABLE = 11;
    IntPtr hModule = LoadLibrary(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\msobjs.dll");
    IntPtr msgTableInfo = FindResource(hModule, 1, RT_MESSAGETABLE);
    IntPtr msgTable = LoadResource(hModule, msgTableInfo);
    IntPtr memTable = LockResource(msgTable);

    int numberOfBlocks = Marshal.ReadInt32(memTable);
    IntPtr blockPtr = IntPtr.Add(memTable, 4);
    int blockSize = Marshal.SizeOf<MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocks; i++) {
        var block = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK>(blockPtr);
        IntPtr entryPtr = IntPtr.Add(memTable, block.OffsetToEntries);

        for (int id = block.LowId; id <= block.HighId; id++) {
            var length = Marshal.ReadInt16(entryPtr);
            var flags = Marshal.ReadInt16(entryPtr, 2);
            var textPtr = IntPtr.Add(entryPtr, 4);
            var text = "Bad flags??";
            if (flags == 0) {
                text = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(textPtr);
            }
            else if (flags == 1) {
                text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(textPtr);
            }
            text = text.Replace("\r\n", "");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", id, text);
            entryPtr = IntPtr.Add(entryPtr, length);
        }
        blockPtr = IntPtr.Add(blockPtr, blockSize);
    }
}
```

Output in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode:

```
279 : Undefined Access (no effect) Bit 7
1536 : Unused message ID
1537 : DELETE
1538 : READ_CONTROL
1539 : WRITE_DAC
1540 : WRITE_OWNER
1541 : SYNCHRONIZE
1542 : ACCESS_SYS_SEC
1543 : MAX_ALLOWED
1552 : Unknown specific access (bit 0)
1553 : Unknown specific access (bit 1)
1554 : Unknown specific access (bit 2)
1555 : Unknown specific access (bit 3)
1556 : Unknown specific access (bit 4)
1557 : Unknown specific access (bit 5)
...etc...
```

Do keep in mind that you will not be reading the file you think you are when you use the jitter forcing to run the program in 32-bit mode.  The file system redirector will get you to read C:\WINDOWS\SysWow64\msobjs.dll instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that DWORD was platform dependent, that's why I had declared it as IntPtr.

Comment: @Paolo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

From Hans Passant's answer:

> DWORD is a 32-bit integer.

Actually, `DWORD` is a 32-bit **unsiged** integer.

The `struct` definition for `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK` that Hans Passant has in the accepted answer is incorrect and while it may work in some cases, it will also eventually lead to errors.

The `LowId` and `HighId` properties should be defined as `uint`. (And while the same would technically be true for the `OffsetToEntries` property, doing so isn't compatible with the standard `IntPrt` addition. Since an offset isn't going to be more than `Int32.MaxValue`, the `OffsetToEntries` can remain an `int`. Therefore:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK
{
    public uint LowId;
    public uint HighId;

    /// <summary>This should technically be a uint, but IntPtr addition doesn't accept that.</summary>
    public int OffsetToEntries;
}
```

You can see the difference if you load the message table for `C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll`. In there, you will find:

```
2205548545 Invalid operation performed by the protocol.
```

If the `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK` `struct` definition used `int`, it would instead return `-2089418751` as the `id` value. But as an example usage, within the `Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Compute-Admin` Event Log, event ID 10018 contains a data parameter of `%%2205548545`, as seen in this screen shot:
[image: Screen shot of Event Viewer with event record parameters.]

So when you are processing that event record and if you were to attempt to match up that parameter's message table ID with your message table IDs, you wouldn't find a match if your `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK` `struct` is defined with `int`, as opposed to `uint`.

Comment: Also, while it make work in some cases, you should switch to using `LoadLibraryEx()` with the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag, as opposed to using the plain `LoadLibrary()`. (And then also call `FreeLibrary()` afterwards.)